# js escape => android decode

Tags: javascript, android

I encoded a string using js method:

```
var result = escape('Вася')
```

and get as result: "%u0412%u0430%u0441%u044F"

how can I decode this string in Java?

This doesn't work:

```
URLDecoder.decode(text, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI), which more-less is equivalent to [`URLEncoder.encode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which in turn happen to be the reverse of `URLDecoder.decode()`. You may also try with `encodeURIComponent()` which handles non-ASCII characters more graciously.